# What OpenMP instructions to be added into code for a multithread matrix determinant calculator?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

Here is a problem I need to handle to complete a matrix determinant calculator. Its algorithm must implement some multithread features, particularly computing result by 2 or higher number of simultaneously running threads. After getting a basic experience with theory, I picked OpenMP to proceed with coding, so just take a look at function definition I seek any solution for:

```
    void calcDeterm(std::vector<std::vector<double>> &input) {
    int i, j, k;
    double temp;

    long double determSeq = 1; // single thread matrix det
    long double determPar = 1; // multithread matrix det


    omp_set_dynamic(0);
    omp_set_num_threads(2);

    #pragma omp parallel for private(j,k,temp) shared(i)
    for (i = 0; i < inputPar.size(); i++) {            
        for (j = i + 1; j < inputPar.size(); j++) {
            if (inputPar[i][i] == 0) {
                if (inputPar[i][j] == 0)
                    temp = 0;
            } else
                temp = inputPar[j][i] / inputPar[i][i];
                for (k = i; k < inputPar.size(); k++)
                    inputPar[j][k] = inputPar[j][k] - inputPar[i][k] * temp;

        }
        std::cout << omp_get_num_threads() << std::endl;
    }

    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(*:determPar)
    for (i = 0; i < inputPar.size(); i++)
        determPar *= inputPar[i][i];


   ...

}
```

This code operates two parallel threads and both are existing whenever the whole program gets tested. The only issue arises once I see outputs provided by single- and multithread algorithms - comparing them, I find out significant difference throughout test series here. In fact, the function which code posted above, produces definitely wrong outcome as it fails to be verified by online calculator with determinant option embedded. Conversely, same function works orderly if #pragma instructions are omitted at all. This way I wonder if its possible to fix mistakes that cause such a gap between only- and multithread results.

Comment: You can avoid the use of private and shared omp variables by declaring variables _when you first use them_, and not all at the top of the function.  Also, think about what value `temp` will have when `inputPar[i][i] == 0` and `inputPar[i][j] != 0`.

Comment: You need to realize that with OMP, the loop `for (i = 0; i < inputPar.size(); i++)` will be done by several threads in parallel, each thread with it's own i value. They are not done in inreasing i order. You cannot know if thread with i value 2 for instance will be executed before thread with i value 3. I think the line `temp = inputPar[j][i] / inputPar[i][i]` (transposition of some sort) make an assumption on the fact i loops are done in "order"